# How to define a angular function

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove the following proposition.

proposition: Let $z:I=[a,b]\to \mathbb{C}$ be continuous and never vanishing on $I$. Then there exits a function $\theta:I\to\mathbb{R}$ such that

$1.$ $\theta$ is continuous on $I$

$2.$ for any $t\in I$, $\theta(t)≡arg\ z(t)\ (mod\ 2\pi)$

In order to prove the proposition, I put the following lemma.

lemma: Let $z$ be the same as above, then there exists $w\in\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ such that the half-line $0w$ intersects the curve $C:z=z(t)\ (t\in I)$ at most only finite times.

Is this lemma true? please give me some advise. thanks.

Comment: I think you would be better off tagging this post with "complex-analysis" rather than "real-analysis".

Comment: @ K.defaoite Thank you for your comment. I have changed the tags.

Comment: not sure if the lemma is true - check Osgood curves https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osgood_curve   - to prove the proposition one can (by uniform continuity and non-vanishing) split $[a,b]$ in small intervals $a=t_0<t_1<...t_k=b$ where the variation of the function $z$ on $[t_k,t_{k+1}]$ is less than the minimum of its absolute value on $[a,b]$ and then (by induction) modify the non-continuos ($\arg$) representation $z(t)=|z(t)|\arg (z(t)), \arg z(t) \in [0, 2\pi)$ by adding some multiple of $2\pi$ at each $t_k$ to make the argument continuos